# How to combine regex + UPDATE in MySQL to add a space to FirstnameLastname

Tags: mysql, regex, select

**A TWO-PARTER:**

**OVERALL ISSUE:** 
I'm trying to correct a `post_title` entry on hundreds of records. They were imported as 'JohnDoe' when they should have been 'John Doe'

**PART the 1st:**
In MySQL, trying to `SELECT` all that match a lowercase followed by Uppercase [aZ] with:

```
SELECT  `post_title` 
FROM wp_posts
WHERE  `post_title` 
REGEXP  '[a-z]\S[A-Z]'
```

However, that also retrieves instances of 'Dr. John Doe', which is actually a correct entry. I need it **only** to retrieve it when the Uppercase directly follows a lowercase, and only when there are NO spaces in the string whatsoever

**PART the 2nd:**
I'm trying to then UPDATE those SELECTED records by adding a space character in between the first and last names. Not sure how to do that exactly with mysql, either. I'm sure it's some kind of crazy Martian nesting of SELECT/UPDATE/WHERE/REGEX statements but that's way beyond me.

No idea.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, pattern matching using REGEXP is case-insensitive. So you've to use BINARY.

I'm not sure if there is a better way of doing this in MySQL but this is one. Run the following queries for each of the alphabet from A to Z. I've given the queries for A, B, C, D, E, Y and Z. Please copy for all other alphabets. Once you've completed running them all, you will have a space between the first and last names

```
UPDATE `wp_posts` 
SET `post_title` = TRIM(REPLACE(`post_title`, 'A', ' A'))
WHERE `post_title` REGEXP BINARY '[A]';

UPDATE `wp_posts` 
SET `post_title` = TRIM(REPLACE(`post_title`, 'B', ' B'))
WHERE `post_title` REGEXP BINARY '[B]';

UPDATE `wp_posts` 
SET `post_title` = TRIM(REPLACE(`post_title`, 'C', ' C'))
WHERE `post_title` REGEXP BINARY '[C]';

UPDATE `wp_posts` 
SET `post_title` = TRIM(REPLACE(`post_title`, 'D', ' D'))
WHERE `post_title` REGEXP BINARY '[D]';

UPDATE `wp_posts` 
SET `post_title` = TRIM(REPLACE(`post_title`, 'E', ' E'))
WHERE `post_title` REGEXP BINARY '[E]';

...
...

UPDATE `wp_posts` 
SET `post_title` = TRIM(REPLACE(`post_title`, 'Y', ' Y'))
WHERE `post_title` REGEXP BINARY '[Y]';

UPDATE `wp_posts` 
SET `post_title` = TRIM(REPLACE(`post_title`, 'Z', ' Z'))
WHERE `post_title` REGEXP BINARY '[Z]';
```

Please note the usage of BINARY in the above query examples.

Another way might be to write a PHP script to read all `post_title` and then use powerful PHP regular expression functions to add spaces and update them back to the database.

Hope this helps!

**EDIT**: Oh! I forgot that the database also has entries with spaces and they need to be ignored. Please use this query instead:

```
UPDATE `wp_posts` 
SET `post_title` = TRIM(REPLACE(`post_title`, 'A', ' A'))
WHERE `post_title` REGEXP BINARY '[^ ][A]';
```

Comment: thank you so much.    

I wound up putting the SQL query you provided into a php loop for simplicity's sake.  


$arr = array(A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z); 

foreach($arr AS $value){
$updateSQL = sprintf("UPDATE `wp_posts` <br/>  
SET `post_title` = TRIM(REPLACE(`post_title`, '$value', ' $value')) 
WHERE `post_title` REGEXP BINARY '[^ ][$value]';");

echo "<p>$updateSQL</p>";
  mysql_select_db($database, $connect); 
  $Result1 = mysql_query($updateSQL, $connect) or die(mysql_error()); 
 
}

Comment: That's a perfect thing to do @MaxRocket :-)