# RegEx with MySql Update

Tags: mysql, regex

I've used

```
SELECT * 
  FROM TABLE
 WHERE BINARY Field REGEXP '[a-z][A-Z]+[a-z]'
```

in order to find wordWord type content.

I am wondering if I can use that in update/replace. Not sure exactly how I'd construct that though the desired outcome of course is `wordWord` becomes `word Word`.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, mysql's `REGEXP` operator only returns boolean.

So you can only check if some string matches some expression, and that's it.

Comment: Interesting, I came across this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8280511/how-to-combine-regex-update-in-mysql-to-add-a-space-to-firstnamelastname?rq=1  which would seem to do exactly what i want in a very brute force-ish kind of way.

Comment: @Mark H: you don't even need a regular expression then `LIKE '%C%'` etc